# searching for anime that aired somewhere 2004-2006 on Toonami

Tags: story-identification, anime

Im searching for anime that aired somewhere 2004-2006 on Toonami . It aired when DBZ started airing. Characters threw some kind of stones with powers that gave rise to monsters or something. It aired at 5:30 or 6pm after DBZ

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and "tropey" and would be greatly improved by addressing the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Looking through [a Wikia article](https://toonami.fandom.com/wiki/Toonami_Lineups_(2004-2008)) I found nothing

Comment: That seems a bit broad. _Huntik_? _Pokémon_? _Digata_? _Magi Nation_? Please [edit] your question to include more details, otherwise there are too many possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The show that [ran in the timeslot](https://toonami.fandom.com/wiki/Toonami_Lineups_(2004-2008)) after DBZ on Toonami from 2004-2006 was *[Duel Masters](https://toonami.fandom.com/wiki/Duel_Masters)*.

> Shobu Kirifuda loves to play the trading-card game, Duel Masters. For many, Duel Masters is just a fun game, but for others it is much more. A few elite players can actually bring the card creatures to life. Doing so requires passion and discipline, as well as a type of martial art, Kaijudo, "The Art of Battling with Giant Monsters," which helps develop and strengthen this ability. Shobu is a good and passionate duelist, but has yet to learn his true potential. He quickly discovers that he can tap into the power of an alternate dimension where creatures and the magic in the game actually exist. Shobu learns that, like his father before him, he possesses the power to be a Kaijudo master. As Shobu continues to search for his missing father, who has vanished into the card dimension, he gains notoriety and skill as a duelist and is often guided by memories of his father. What appears to be an ordinary game becomes a very real battle for Shobu. This power brings him in contact with others who share this ability, some good and some evil.

One of the things that might have stuck with you was that they introduced metatextual gags with the American dub.

### Shobu's first win

Found by searching for `toonami 2004 schedule`. It's not throwing stones, but throwing cards is similar, and they do summon monsters to duel.

Comment: If this is correct, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I doubt this is it. I watched the trailer and it’s nothing like throwing stones.

Comment: @Stormblessed: It's the best fit among the Toonami shoes in that time period. Unless we consider that they're looking at the 2006 airing of *Pokemon*...